# How to pass variable to Laravel Validator Rule

Tags: php, validation, laravel

### The Issue

Consider this:

```
protected $rules = array(
    'mobile_number' => 'phone:AUTO,mobile,:country_code'
);
```

In the above example, the value of `country_code` needs to change dependant on a variable defined prior to the validation taking place.

With this in mind, is it possible to pass a variable into a Laravel Validation rule?

Please bear in mind, this is how I call my validation:

```
if(!$this->some_validator->with($data)->passes()){

    // Get the validation errors and throw the exception
    $error_info = $this->some_validator->formatErrorMessages();
    throw new ExampleException(ExampleExceptionType::$VALIDATION_ERROR,$error_info);
}
```

Comment: Make the `country_code` variable global and access it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to create custom validation rules.

It looks like this:

```
Validator::extend('country_code', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        if ($value === 'US') {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

And then just use it like this:

```
    protected $rules = array(
    'mobile_number' => 'phone:AUTO,mobile|country_code'
);
```

After re-reading your message I realized that you meant a bit different thing. But take a look at the `$parameters` argument.
And read documentation. It's quite well covered there https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

With the new way of doing this, if you extend a new rule and you have a variable that you want to pass to the closure, you can do it like this:

```
  Validator::extend(nameOfTheRule, function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) use ($priorVariable) {
  //code
```

}